# Qual a diferença entre computed properties e os methods de uma instância do Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js

Estou tentando entender a diferença entre os dois, quando usar um ou outro, sei que existem também os watchers, qual o uso correto deles?

Comment: Boa resposta a isso aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44350862/method-vs-computed-in-vue . Mas uma das princípais diferenças é que os methods podem ser chamados com argumentos. ex: `v-on:click="add(1,2)"`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Num componente Vue temos de ter as coisas organizadas, para isso existem alguns conceitos/parametros a ter em conta e que são a maneira de funcionar de um componente.

#### methods

Aqui deves guardar funções. Todo o tipo de funções que tratam dados e funcionalidade do componente.

Guardando essas funções no methods permite que eles sejam usados noutros componentes, por herança ou por grau de parentesco.

Aqui podes também importar métodos da store.

#### data

Aqui deves guardas primitivos. Strings, arrays, objectos, etc. No fundo o estado do componente.

#### computed

Aqui tens uma mistura dos dois anteriores, e entra a lógica/metodologia de programação reactiva. Estes métodos são funções que retornam dados são provaveis de terem sido alterados entre renderizações. Imagina um exemplo:

Tens uma imagem no componente e queres pegar no canto para a fazer maior. Algures na lógica vais ter de dizer qual o `width`, `height` dessa imagem. Depois queres arrastar (fazer drag) dela e vais ter de controlar o `left` e `top` dessa imagem.

Ora em vêz de ter um 4 valores espalhados no `data`, e depois no template uma misturada com esses valores tipo: `<img :styles=""` que fica meio dificil de manter; o mellhor é ter um `computed` para isso:

```
computed: 
    styles(){
        return {left: this.left, top: this.top, height: this.height, width: this.width};
    }
}
```

e no template fica bem mais limpo com somente `<img :styles="styles"`.

Outra funcionalidade muito util é podermos importar da store os getters que vão para `computed` e os métodos da store que vão para os `methods` do componente.

#### props

Os dados passados ao componente. Esta é uma das poucas vias de passagem de dados, e permite controlos rígidos de tipagem. O que está no `data` é interno ao componente e possivelmente aos seus descendentes. O que está no `props` são dados para usar no componente e não podem ser mudados diretamente, só via mudança no estado do componente ou parte da aplicação que gera esses dados.

#### watch

Aqui deves guardar métodos que devem ser chamados quando o valor de uma propriedade de `data` ou `props` mudar. Pode haver casos em que funcione usar `computed`, outras `watch`.
Em regra geral, se houver algo que precises saber quando mudou usa `watch`; quando quiseres ter sempre dados atualizados, usa computed.

Comment: tá perfeito, consegui entender, você sabe sobre o watch comparando com o computed?

Comment: @haykou juntei :)